# Adobe Air 32-Bit Unable to Download

Tags: drivers, wine, 21.04, playonlinux, adobe

I am trying to install Photoshop CS 6 through PlayonLinux but get the adobe air error, as it is unable to download it.

Now I have downloaded separately the SDK version (NOT the Compiler)  from this site, but don't know what to do further

https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html

Please help, Thanks :)

**I am following this Tutorial:**

https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-adobe-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-linux/

My Specs:

- Ubuntu 21.04 (64 Bit), Desktop Version
- wine-6.0.1
- PlayOnLinux 4.3.4

Comment: Have you looked on the Wine web site to see if  Photoshop CS 6 has any special needs or set up steps?

Comment: hi, no instructions are given on the site, for how to install :(

Comment: Wine does not have it listed as a supported program?

Comment: wait here is the link, there are no instructions to install it i mean     https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607